# Django foreign keys between abstract models

Tags: python, django, django-models

My django project has multiple apps with the same model structure.
In order to avoid copy-pasting of the models file, I wrote a generic_models file that contains abstract models in that structure, and each app has models that inherit from the generic models.

Two of these tables have foreign keys between them.
I would have liked to define the foreign keys as fields in the abstract models.
Problem is that a foreign key can't point to an abstract table.

How can I achieve this structure?

Comment: It's hard to guess what are the different apps doing, it might still make sense to duplicate them if they really represent completely different thing. Otherwise, I think you could try GenericForeignKey: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work, but at least you can try. 
In ForeignKey definition use related model name as a string instead of related model object, i.e.

`f_key = models.ForeignKey('your_app.Your_model')`

instead of

`f_key = models.ForeignKey(your_app.Your_model)`

, may be even try using `'self'`. Not sure if this is implemented, but it makes sense.

Also see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#lazy-relationships

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name